# Read a file in same directory as the JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, file

I can load an image file located in the same relative path as the JavaScript file

```
var imgObj = new Image(); 
imgObj.src = "images/backdropLevel0.jpg";
```

But how do I do the same (as simply and with pure JavaScript) for a text file ? 
(it has some initial data for a webGL game I am working on).

PS. I am **not** asking about user input from the client's computer using the new File object.

Comment: Make an ajax request for the file and read the `responseText`.

Comment: It would be better if you store the url to the folder in a variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetching an image is easy since the browser takes care of all the fetching and rendering. However, loading an arbitrary file into your script requires a couple more lines:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(){
    process_webgl_data(this.responseText);
};
req.open('GET', './webgl_init.dat');
req.send();
```

Where `process_webgl_data` is whatever you want to do with the text of the file.

EDIT: Two quick things. Remember that request URIs are resolved with respect to the **html file** rather than the script, and second, here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) for XHR.

Comment: Super ! This puts me on the right path. Thank You !

Comment: Can I use fetch API instead?
Like this:
fetch(''./webgl_init.dat'').then(r=>r.text()).then(process_webgl_data)

Comment: Certainly! `fetch` wasn't nearly as widespread when I posted this response as it is today.

Answer (score 1):

You can also archive the same using fetch JavaScript API
Example:

```
fetch('./webgl_init.dat').then(r=>r.text()).then(process_webgl_data)
```